# sending git project by email git security

Tags: git, github

Would sending a entire project to someone by email along with the .git folder exposes security issues? For example can it happen that the receiver uses this to access by **ssh** or **https** other projects from the senders GitHub account. 
The project is created in Intelij, is it possible that some Intelij files expose a security problem concerning git hub credentials?

Comment: If you want to share a repository with others by email, you could try `git bundle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not, but there could be exceptions here and there:

- if you added url like `http://user:password@site/git/..` to remotes
- if your credential helper stores the data inside .git folder (I have no idea if there is some which do)
- if you have ever staged a file with secret information - even not committed, those could be found with fsck
- whatever I forgot about

It is really better to send a bundle as suggsested in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151847/sending-git-project-by-email-git-security#comment87321576_50151847)